# How do you create a guest on a guestlist in Social Tables API?

Tags: social-tables

My bearer token is working fine, as I'm able to pull data from my account no problem.

However, when I try to POST to api.socialtables.com/4.0/guestlist/{guestlist_id}/guests with this body, it gives me a "BadRequestError" and no message.

```
{
"checked_in_status": {
  "checked_in": 0,
  "checked_in_at": null,
  "checked_out_at": null
},
"email": "frank@nelsonandmurdock.com",
"first_name": "Frank",
"group_id": null,
"hasImage": false,
"has_disability": false,
"id": "c4544430-65f1-11e7-831d-df09b6be9025",
"last_name": "Nelson",
"organization": "Nelson & Murdock",
"tags": [
  "Splash"
],
"title": "Partner",
```

}

Is there something wrong with what I'm submitting? What's the minimum that I can submit to add a new guest to a particular guest list?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reaching out.

Could you provide the `guestlist_id` you're using for this call?

The body you submitted should work with a valid guest list and the removal of the last comma `"title": "Partner",`

```
{
 "checked_in_status": {
  "checked_in": 0,
  "checked_in_at": null,
  "checked_out_at": null
 },
 "email": "frank@nelsonandmurdock.com",
 "first_name": "Frank",
 "group_id": null,
 "hasImage": false,
 "has_disability": false,
 "id": "c4544430-65f1-11e7-831d-df09b6be9025",
 "last_name": "Nelson",
 "organization": "Nelson & Murdock",
 "tags": [
  "Splash"
 ],
 "title": "Partner"
}
```

The minimum requirements for a valid guest is having a `first_name` and `last_name`. So you're body at the very least would need to be:

```
{
 "first_name": "Frank",
 "last_name": "Nelson"
}
```

Comment: https://api.socialtables.com/4.0/guestlists/78fe5a50-65e9-11e7-831d-df09b6be9025/guests

Comment: Have you had success with the simplified body?

Comment: No, still getting:  

'{
  "code": "BadRequestError",
  "message": ""
}'

Comment: @TimAlexander I've submitted an update to our code base that should return a better error for you. Will ping you again once it has been deployed.

Comment: @TimAlexander go ahead and try your request again. You should now receive a message with errors if your body fails validation. Let me know if you continue to get no message.

Comment: seems like it wasn't detecting first name or last name. However, I reconstructed the request from scratch, and it suddenly worked. I'm not sure what happened there, but it seems to work now. Thank you!